# Visual Studio Code 1.52 SCSS Emmet behavior changed

Tags: visual-studio-code

quick question for the VSCode experts among you.

In the recently released November update, Emmet in SCSS no longer works as expected. For example, when typing `v:h` I'd expect to get `visibility: hidden;`.

However, in the new version, this would result in `v:map-has-key($map: , $key: )`.

I have searched through the changelog but have no idea what causes this behavior. Do you have any suggestions on how to restore the previous behavior? I have downgraded to 1.51 for now.

1.51 Screenshot

[image: 1.51 Screenshot]

1.52 Screenshot

[image: 1.52 Screenshot]

Comment: you can look in the emmet extension and see if the `v:h` is still defined in the source code

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't occur only with `v:h` but basically all abbreviations.

Comment: First, can you try expanding that suggestions box by dragging its lower border down.  And report back what you see and if you could expand it.

Comment: Expanding the box by dragging on it doesn't reveal any new information, unfortunately.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66805005/836330 this has been fixed and will be in v1.55 due very soon.

Answer (score 0):

**Vss 1.52
Notable fixes**

*98041: Emmet ignores selection on Evaluate Math Expression*

Probably related to this fix, because it started showing mathematical functions