# How to get Emmet in VScode for SCSS to act more like it does for CSS

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, emmet

Default Emmet autocomplete in VSCode for scss are not helpful:

e.g.

"pos:a" gives "pos:abs($number: 0)" when I want "position: absolute;"

"fs:i" gives "fs:index($list: , $value: )" when I want "font-style: italic;"

etc...

How to fix?

[image]

Comment: change the language of the file to `css`, are there multiple snippets you can choose for, the CSS version might be one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the Insiders Build and will be in v1.55 Stable.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112675

Your test case work fine today in the Insiders:

`"fs:i" => "font-style: italic;"`

`"pos:a" => "position: absolute;"`

Answer (score 1):

Are you using scss or sass files? I believe emmet should work out of the box for scss, and perhaps you should install this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Syler.sass-indented) for emmet to work with sass files.

You can check this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32281) too.

You can also try this in settings.json:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "SCSS": "CSS"
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the issue is with scss.

Comment: That's odd. What's the file language you see on your status bar, on the right side of it? You should see "SCSS". If you click on it you get offered the options to configure file associations and settings for the type of file.

Comment: Thanks, the Language is set to "SCSS". From your response I assumed there was something funky with my setup but I've just tried this on a fresh install of VSC. Create a file test.scss -> create an element -> inside of element type "pos:a" -> tab -> resolves to "pos:abs($number: 0)". "position:absolute" isn't even given as an option. I've added a screen recording gif to my question to show.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a new hint.

Comment: Thanks @Guillermo, good thinking but it didn't work. Actually I've just realised that everything I have tried seems to work if I just omit the colon so maybe the problem is not so bad.

Answer (score 1):

See image by clicking and follow step by step:

[F1 and write "snippet"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz039.png)

[Search scss and click or enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALLym.png)

[Copy or writing next code. Save and Testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jntbI.png)

```
"example posabs": {
        "prefix": "posa",
        "body": [
            "position: absolute;",
        ],
        "description": "example for you"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that is useful to patch things but it would be better if I could just get emmet to work.